# Using Reshape from wide to long in R

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to reshape Data from wide to long in R.

my data in wide format looks like this:

I have the following  Data-Matrix: 
in the rows i have the different companies, and in the columns in have different variables from different years. (earnings_2012, earnings_2011, earnings_2010,...,tot_assets_2012,tot_assets_2011, and so on.

I would like to rearrange this into a long format:

having only these columns: company, year, variables (earnings,tot_assets,..)

I've been trying for days now. I also consulted http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/reshape.htm for help but i could not grasp how they reshaped their data and how to detach the year.

Thank you in advance for your help.

regards

Gritti

PS: Since I am new to R and the provided help in R itself seems to be rather technical I appreciate any hints for a very simple introduction.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  Read this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: You may also want to look at the package `reshape2` and understand how to use a `melt()` and `dcast()`.

Comment: You definitely need to add at least what you have tried so far as an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are three examples (along with some sample data that I think is representative of what you described).

Here's the sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(
  company = LETTERS[1:4],
  earnings_2012 = runif(4),
  earnings_2011 = runif(4),
  earnings_2010 = runif(4),
  assets_2012 = runif(4),
  assets_2011 = runif(4),
  assets_2010 = runif(4)
)

mydf
#   company earnings_2012 earnings_2011 earnings_2010 assets_2012 assets_2011 assets_2010
# 1       A     0.2655087     0.2016819    0.62911404   0.6870228   0.7176185   0.9347052
# 2       B     0.3721239     0.8983897    0.06178627   0.3841037   0.9919061   0.2121425
# 3       C     0.5728534     0.9446753    0.20597457   0.7698414   0.3800352   0.6516738
# 4       D     0.9082078     0.6607978    0.17655675   0.4976992   0.7774452   0.1255551
```

#### Option 1: `reshape`

*One limitation is that it won't handle "unbalanced" datasets (for example, if you didn't have "assets_2010" as part of your data, this wouldn't work).*

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "long", idvar="company", 
        varying = 2:ncol(mydf), sep = "_")
#        company time   earnings    assets
# A.2012       A 2012 0.26550866 0.6870228
# B.2012       B 2012 0.37212390 0.3841037
# C.2012       C 2012 0.57285336 0.7698414
# D.2012       D 2012 0.90820779 0.4976992
# A.2011       A 2011 0.20168193 0.7176185
# B.2011       B 2011 0.89838968 0.9919061
# C.2011       C 2011 0.94467527 0.3800352
# D.2011       D 2011 0.66079779 0.7774452
# A.2010       A 2010 0.62911404 0.9347052
# B.2010       B 2010 0.06178627 0.2121425
# C.2010       C 2010 0.20597457 0.6516738
# D.2010       D 2010 0.17655675 0.1255551
```

#### Option 2: The "reshape2" package

*Quite popular for its syntax. Needs a little bit of processing before it can work since the column names need to be split in order for us to get this "double-wide" type of data. Is able to handle unbalanced data, but won't be the best if your varying columns are of different column types (numeric, character, factor).*

```
library(reshape2)
dfL <- melt(mydf, id.vars="company")
dfL <- cbind(dfL, colsplit(dfL$variable, "_", c("var", "year")))
dcast(dfL, company + year ~ var, value.var="value")
#    company year    assets   earnings
# 1        A 2010 0.9347052 0.62911404
# 2        A 2011 0.7176185 0.20168193
# 3        A 2012 0.6870228 0.26550866
# 4        B 2010 0.2121425 0.06178627
# 5        B 2011 0.9919061 0.89838968
# 6        B 2012 0.3841037 0.37212390
# 7        C 2010 0.6516738 0.20597457
# 8        C 2011 0.3800352 0.94467527
# 9        C 2012 0.7698414 0.57285336
# 10       D 2010 0.1255551 0.17655675
# 11       D 2011 0.7774452 0.66079779
# 12       D 2012 0.4976992 0.90820779
```

#### Option 3: `merged.stack` from "splitstackshape"

*`merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package has pretty straightforward syntax and should be pretty fast if you need to end up with this "double-wide" type of structure. It was created to be able to handle unbalanced data and since it treats columns separately, won't have problems with converting column types.*

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(mydf, id.vars="company", 
             var.stubs=c("earnings", "assets"), sep = "_")
#     company .time_1   earnings    assets
#  1:       A    2010 0.62911404 0.9347052
#  2:       A    2011 0.20168193 0.7176185
#  3:       A    2012 0.26550866 0.6870228
#  4:       B    2010 0.06178627 0.2121425
#  5:       B    2011 0.89838968 0.9919061
#  6:       B    2012 0.37212390 0.3841037
#  7:       C    2010 0.20597457 0.6516738
#  8:       C    2011 0.94467527 0.3800352
#  9:       C    2012 0.57285336 0.7698414
# 10:       D    2010 0.17655675 0.1255551
# 11:       D    2011 0.66079779 0.7774452
# 12:       D    2012 0.90820779 0.4976992
```

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot for your help. I just downloaded your package. They only thing in my data is different is that i don't have a column with the company, however the company is included in the row.names of my data. Do i have to add another column in order make your function work?

Comment: @Gritti, yes. You can add the rownames in quite easily. Something like `mydf$company <- rownames(mydf)` should do it.

Comment: thank you again for the great help. it worked like a charm. is there also an easy way to delete certain rows with this package? For example if i decide that i want to erase all observations that happened in year 2012.

Comment: @Gritti, just reshape to the long form, and use the basic subsetting tools available with R. See `help(Extract)` for more details.

Comment: Thanks again for your inputs, I've come across another problem where i'm trying basically the same as before, but now i have other repeating variables next to company. i tried to switch the id.vars command to id.vars=c("company", "sector") , however i retrieve the following error: Error in names(x) <- c(".var", paste(".time", 1:(length(x) - 1), sep = "_")) : 
  'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [0]     Does the order in var.stubs play a role and have to be according to the dataframe?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Option 3 works so easy!