# reshape2 melt function on timestamps gives NAs

Tags: r, timestamp, reshape2

I’m trying to melt a data frame with reshape2 `melt` function, in order to plot my dataset with ggplot2. However, with my reference column, containing a timestamp, it gives me `NA` after first iteration (timestamps are correctly displayed once each, and then I have these `NA`s).

Here is my dataset:

```
TIMESTAMP,RECNUM,Tair,Tground
2015-01-06 16:27,1,5.0,7.0
2015-01-06 16:28,2,6.0,7.0
2015-01-06 16:29,3,6.0,7.0
2015-01-06 16:30,4,6.5,7.0
2015-01-06 16:31,5,6.8,7.1
2015-01-06 16:32,6,6.8,7.1
2015-01-06 16:33,7,6.8,7.12
2015-01-06 16:34,8,7.1,7.1
2015-01-06 16:35,9,7.15,7.09
2015-01-06 16:36,10,7.18,7.1
2015-01-06 16:37,11,7.3,7.1
```

My R code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
datafile <- file.choose()
dat <- read.csv(datafile)
dat$TIMESTAMP <- as.POSIXlt(strptime(dat$TIMESTAMP,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
meltedData = melt(dat, id.vars=c("RECNUM", "TIMESTAMP"), variable.name="Measure")
```

And the resulting `meltedData` variable:

```
> meltedData
   RECNUM           TIMESTAMP Measure value
1       1 2015-01-06 16:27:00    Tair  5.00
2       2 2015-01-06 16:28:00    Tair  6.00
3       3 2015-01-06 16:29:00    Tair  6.00
4       4 2015-01-06 16:30:00    Tair  6.50
5       5 2015-01-06 16:31:00    Tair  6.80
6       6 2015-01-06 16:32:00    Tair  6.80
7       7 2015-01-06 16:33:00    Tair  6.80
8       8 2015-01-06 16:34:00    Tair  7.10
9       9 2015-01-06 16:35:00    Tair  7.15
10     10 2015-01-06 16:36:00    Tair  7.18
11     11 2015-01-06 16:37:00    Tair  7.30
12      1                <NA> Tground  7.00
13      2                <NA> Tground  7.00
14      3                <NA> Tground  7.00
15      4                <NA> Tground  7.00
16      5                <NA> Tground  7.10
17      6                <NA> Tground  7.10
18      7                <NA> Tground  7.12
19      8                <NA> Tground  7.10
20      9                <NA> Tground  7.09
21     10                <NA> Tground  7.10
22     11                <NA> Tground  7.10
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is there a way to have proper timestamps all table long ?

Thanks,

J.

**Edit**
This question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23167827/using-reshape-from-wide-to-long-in-r), as my question is not oriented on how to use reshape2 to change frow wide to long, but on why do `reshape2::melt` gives me `NA`s on timestamps.

Comment: or simply use `dput(dataset)`

Comment: @nicola I don't see where is the comma missing. In the dataset?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Your example is fine.

Comment: I do not get the NA's. Works fine for me.

Comment: The problem arises for `as.POSIXlt` which is a `list`. Use `as.POSIXct` instead and you'll be fine.

Comment: @akrun I reopened the question since the problem here arises from the fact that there is a `POSIXlt` column (which is actually a `list`) and `melt` doesn't handle it. So, OP here isn't asking how to reshape data, but rather why reshaping here doesn't work.

Comment: @nicola okay, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code arises from the fact that you have coerced your `TIMESTAMP` column to `POSIXlt`. Keep in mind that `POSIXlt` and `POSIXct`, while very similar from the exterior, are way different. `POSIXlt` is actually a list. Try for instance:

```
x<-as.POSIXlt("2017-01-15 15:00:00")
typeof(x)
#[1] "list"
unclass(x)
#$sec
#[1] 0
#$min
#[1] 0
#$hour
#[1] 15
#$mday
#[1] 15
#...
```

As you can see, a `POSIXlt` object is a `list` with elements indicating the seconds, minutes, hour and so on of a date. Let's `POSIXct`:

```
x<-as.POSIXct("2017-01-15 15:00:00")
typeof(x)
#[1] "double"
unclass(x)
#[1] 1484488800
#attr(,"tzone")
#[1] ""
```

`POSIXct` on the other hand are just the number of seconds from the UNIX epoch and so the date can be stored as just a single number. `POSIXct` are lighter than `POSIXlt`.

While it is possible to have a column in a `data.frame` which is a list, it's much better to have `POSIXct`:

```
dat$TIMESTAMP <- as.POSIXct(strptime(dat$TIMESTAMP,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
#this works now as intended
melt(dat, id.vars=c("RECNUM", "TIMESTAMP"), variable.name="Measure")
```